# Grails one to one on two domain object

Tags: grails, grails-2.2

I want to add a child to two different parent class, like that:

First:

```
class Member {
    Profile profile

    Member() {
        this.profile = new Profile()
    }

    static mapping = {
        profile cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    }
}
```

Second:

```
class Team {
    Profile profile

    Team() {
        this.profile = new Profile()
    }

    static mapping = {
        profile cascade: 'all-delete-orphan'
    }
}
```

Thw child is simply define like that

```
  class Profile() {
  }
```

The probleme is when I save the parent, it dosent save the child:

```
Member member = new Member().save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

assert !member.hasErrors()
assert member.profile           
assert !member.profile.hasErrors()

assert member.profile.id //FAIL
```

What do I do wrong?  Is there a better way to do it?

**UPDATE:**

I found this

[Saving associated domain classes in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041992/saving-associated-domain-classes-in-grails/1047132#1047132)

It seem that 'belong to' is needed for that kind of behavior. But Why the 'cascade: 'all-delete-orphan' doesn't force this ? Because I can't use 'belong to' in that specific case

Comment: where is `group` defined in `Member`?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake typing my question. It's corrected now, thanks to have pointed it!

Comment: Are you flushing?  `.save(flush: true)`

Comment: Yeah, it seam to have a probleme with the session.flush while in a unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution. The best was to define both parent in the child but nullable. Like that:

```
class Profile() {
    static belongsTo = [member: Member, team: Team]

    static constraints = {
        member nullable: true
        team nullable: true
    }
}
```

This way, the cascade behavior work just fine !

Answer (score 0):

I copied your example (with slight modification to change group table name to a non-reserved word) and the cascades are working properly using grails 2.2.1. Both `Member` and `Group` cascaded their saves to the newly created `Profiles`.

Assuming your classes are more complicated than this, you might have an error elsewhere in your class (eg cascade behavior described in `constraints` instead of `mapping`, etc).